# How to run a (dot)java file

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction

I've been looking around for a tutorial on how to compile/run a java file. I know you can run it and compile it with eclipse, and you can type "javac" in terminal (mac), but i would like to send a small program i wrote to a friend, and he can just click on it to run it. Maybe a class file, I don't know. I am running mac btw.

Comment: If you have an IDE, clean and build the project.  If required, export it to a Jar file, making sure it's executable and send that.  Take a look at [Packing Programs in Jar Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html) for more details.  In general they should be able to double click the Jar file and have it run automatically...assuming they have Java installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all create an executable JAR File and then-

You can create-

1. a batch file(.bat) for windows like this,

   ```
   @echo off
   start javaw -jar XYZ.jar
   ```

   save this file to ABC.bat, now this file is executable,
       just double click on it and run your program.
2. an executable file(.exe) for windows, like this,

   This is a C program-

   ```
   ‪#‎include‬ <string.h> 
   #include <stdlib.h>  

   void main (int argc, char **args) {
       char *jarfile = "XYZ.jar"; // jar file name...
       int n = strlen(jarfile);
       char *cmd = (char *)malloc(n+50);
       strcpy(cmd, "startw java -jar ");
       strcat(cmd, jarfile);
       system(cmd);
   }
   ```

   compile this file with any c compiler, now run the executable file(.exe).

Answer (score 3):

Make it a runnable jar from eclipse.
Your main file will run.

A good tutorial if you need @ [Create a Java exe file / executable JAR](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file/)

HTH